# How can I write email replies in interleaved-quoted-reply format with Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Unfortunately for me, I'm using MS Outlook (stuck with Windows and Exchange and weird authentication mechanisms). I want to reply to a certain email with my reply not appearing entirely above or below the original message, but interspersed - you know, the reasonable, traditional way you can write replies on any normal mail client, i.e. something like:

```
On Apr 1st 2020, 12:34, Some One <some@one.com> wrote:
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
> Nulla nec porttitor ex. Mauris magna odio, sollicitudin 

Part of the reply here.

> at arcu quis, aliquam accumsan odio. Fusce sed turpis
> ante. Morbi ultrices, mi sit amet pellentesque semper,
> nibh nibh pellentesque ligula, ac ultricies mi dui eget
> erat. Cras ut porta ipsum, sit amet pharetra ante. 
> Curabitur imperdiet bibendum ultrices. Cras nec 
> accumsan turpis, sit amet laoreet sapien. Nulla sit 

And another part here.

> amet dui neque. Maecenas hendrerit mi ut ante pulvinar,
> sit amet convallis quam tincidunt. 
> Suspendisse accumsan felis in eleifend tincidunt.
```

How can I force Outlook to allow this?

Comment: As far as I know, when you click Reply in a message, you can direct edit its body. This may be a workaround. Besdies, here is a function I want to introduce to you:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-email-messages-by-conversation-0eeec76c-f59b-4834-98e6-05cfdfa9fb07

Comment: @Aidan: I don't want to edit its body. I want it to appear quoted, and for me to be able to intersperse that blockquote with non-quoted lines.

Answer (score 2):

See this:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/reply-with-inline-comments-within-the-original-message-text-5bc44105-aeb2-49e2-8239-5aeeff52e5a7

> Click the File > Options.
>
> In the left pane, click Mail.
>
> In the right pane, under Replies and forwards, check the Preface
>   comments with box, and type the text you want to use to identify your
>   comments

In the "Text" you want to identify your comments, you can either use your initials or full name.

Comment: So, this is better than nothing. However, I doubt this will "scale", i.e. it already looks messy, and when the other party replies with their own inline comments, it'll be difficult to make heads or tails of the message. But that's not your fault of course.

Answer (score 0):

I found this is possible if one sets Outlook to [Read all standard mail in plain text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/read-email-messages-in-plain-text-16dfe54a-fadc-4261-b2ce-19ad072ed7e3).

[Source](http://blog.loftninjas.org/2008/08/14/making-outlook-2007-quote-responsibly/).

However that does make many emails basically unreadable without an extra couple of clicks to render the HTML :-(.

Comment: HTML emails in plain text will have HTML codes in view.  Re-rendering the HTML is converting the email back to an HTML email which defeats the point. As the web link you provided states, it is a security feature many use.